# Backbone and jquerymobile navigation issues - hash in URLs

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, navigation, routes

I am using backbone.js and WebMatrix. I have problems with hash(#) in url though. To be more precise, I have on my router file this code:

```
routes: { 
          ""          : 'myBooks', 
          "books/:id" : 'bookDetails'
}
```

and then i initialize the router

```
var initialization = function () {

        Backbone.history.start();
};
```

So when I click this URL: "localhost:9548/#books/1" on my browser, the following message appears on my console (firebug) "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - //localhost:9548/books/1".
I have found already posts trying to solve a similar problem but I am not at all familiar with IIS Express (server configuration in general). So some posts for example also refer to web.config of my web application but I do not have any.

So for instance if I would create a web.config file with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
            <add key="index.html#books/*" value="index.html" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

would solve my problem?

I apologize that I did not mention the fact that for the ui (and only) of my web app, I am using jquerymobile. Consequently, I have disabled the ajax navigation of jquerymobile:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false; 
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
```

Besides the change of a page is handled by this code:

```
var utility = {}; 
utility.changePage = function( viewID, effect, direction, updateHash ) {
   viewID.attr('data-role', 'page');
   $.mobile.changePage( viewID,{changeHash: updateHash}); 
};
```

Finally the function which handles my route is the following:

```
bookDetail: function (id) { 
   var myBook = myCollection.get(id); 
   var bookDetails = new BookDetails({ model: myBook });
   $('body').append($(bookDetails.render().el));
   $.mobile.changePage(bookDetails.$el, {changeHash: false }); 
}
```

**Important:** There is a chance that the problem is occurred because of the last version of the jquerymobile (1.3.0). Precisely, disabling hashListeningEnabled does not work properly as I have read. 
Another feature is that I encounter this problem with Mozilla and Chrome but not with Internet explorer (using the last version of them).

Comment: Can you show the whole router code?

Comment: URL rewriting problem it seems. Did you use pushState?

Comment: @Chris84 - instead of posting comments just edit your answer

Comment: @Aaron D - sorry and thanks.